# Is it possible to override a field module's implementation of hook_field_validate()?

Tags: 7, entities

I need to override [`hook_field_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_validate/7) for a particular field (provided by the [Video Embed Field](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module). The description for that hook states:

> Validate this module's field data.

So the idea is that it's only invoked for the module that implements a particular field, which makes sense.

Unfortunately there's no altering mechanism in place (that I can find) so the implementations of those hooks are pretty much hard-coded. Also the hook is never run through `module_implements()` (as you would expect), so in turn is not available to be overridden using [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7).

Does anyone know of a way, however unclean, of overriding `hook_field_validate()` for a particular field implementation, without hacking any core/contrib modules?

Comment: The code is aiming a specific function that must be implemented in a specific module (the one implementing the field); that is why the code doesn't use `module_implements()`, nor `module_invoke_all()`. As consequence, `hook_module_implements_alter()` is not invoked too.

Comment: Yeah I understand why it does that (similar to the hooks invoked for node type modules), I'm just trying to find a way to override it. @Oswald's solution looks promising I'm just testing it out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [hook_field_attach_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_validate/7), which is invoked by [the single function that invokes hook_field_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/invokes/hook_field_validate/7), namely [field_attach_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_validate/7), which is called by [field_attach_form_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_form_validate/7).

I did not find an obvious way to get rid of the original validation function, but a quick hack would be to remove the errors, that the original validation function produced, from the `$errors` array in your [hook_field_attach_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_validate/7) implementation.

Comment: As the errors are just returned in that `$errors` array, and they are not yet printed with `drupal_set_message()`, altering the array is the way to go. I was going to answer the question, and I would have given the same answer.

Comment: Thanks both this is definitely the way to go. I had to abandon the whole thing unfortunately because of limitations in the video embed module but I tested this and it works great